# Why is StarCraft 2 divided by regions?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net, region-lock

I live in Argentina, but I love to get all my stuff (be it games, tv series, movies, etc) in English.

Battle.net will only let me select one region, which by default is Latin America, that has only Spanish and Portuguese (not to mention that I only get to play with users in the same region).

What is the logic behind this? Is there a way to play in any region and in any language? (legally of course)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I sent an e-mail to blizzard support, this is what they answered:

> Quality and customer service are the highest priorities for Blizzard Entertainment. **Because we cannot guarantee a positive gaming experience for users connecting to servers outside the supported region, we do not support use outside of the designated region**. You can change which region you are purchasing for by clicking the (change) link next to the region.  I recommend that, if possible, you acquire a localized version of the game for a more positive gaming experience.
>
> In other words, players in one region of the world will not be able to play on alternate regions at this time. This is something that we will continue to investigate as a possibility for the future, however, if you have purchased a version of StarCraft II from outside of your home region we recommend that you return it and purchase the localized version instead.
>
> Please also keep in mind that you will not be able to access your account if you are using a different regional game version (other than your home regions version). For example, you will be unable to connect to the North American realms if using a Chinese, Korean, European, or Taiwanese version of the game.
>
> We recommend that you continue to visit http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/ for the latest announcements and updates on this and other StarCraft II features.
>
> If you have additional questions or concerns, please reply to this email.  If you would rather speak with a representative directly, please contact Account & Technical Services. Our contact information can be found at http://blizzard.com/support/article/cs.

Comment: well that's almost as lame as the "we don't include LAN support since LAN is irrelevant nowadays" excuse

Comment: Yes @Tob, I agree... at least let me choose, I play on servers from around the world with steam and I accept the little lag I get -- If I can play an FPS I will certainly play an RTS with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because Starcraft 2 is region-locked, like most videos, games, and game consoles.

The easiest way to circumvent this region locking is to simply purchase another copy of the game from the region you're seeking to join.

The patient route is to wait until Blizzard gets around to implementing cross-region battle.net.

Edit: Too bad you don't live in Australia: http://www.kotaku.com.au/2010/07/starcraft-ii-will-not-be-region-locked-in-australia/

Comment: Are there any plans to implement that?

Comment: I could have sworn I read something about it, but I haven't been able to find anything yet...

Answer (score 1):

The another reason is maybe because of different pricing policy made by Blizzard. For example unlimited euro version costs 60 euro, while russian one is twice chipper. Maybe somebody will be unpleased that he had to pay more then another for the same server.

Comment: meh... everything else has different prices according to where you live; food, clothes, electronics -- I can accept that.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a legitimate concern over latency.  I know the Internet is pretty international, but the simple fact is if I'm in Alberta, my average latency relative to someone in Texas will generally be shorter than my latency relative to someone in South Africa.

Comment: Sure, but should they prohibit me to play? Steam lets me choose where to play -- obviously I prefer to play on servers in my location, but what if I want to play against a specific user? We can't if we're in different regions unless I buy an additional copy.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons invoked by Activision are absolute garbage. In SC1 we could simply reconnect to a different server OF YOUR CHOICE. The real reason is that your account is tied to a specific server. If you have a bro/sis, you need another account and you need to buy another copy. It all boils down to milking your fanbase for more money.

Answer (score -1):

**Why is StarCraft 2 divided by regions?**

Blizzard/Activision decided so and for the moment, you cannot do anything about it.

**I love to get all my stuff [...] in English**

You could try to persuade Blizzard/Activision to add the English language to your region. It might actually be easier than opening the regions since the English version is already available in other regions.

I bought Starcraft 2 in France and got a French version, but I was able to download an English version from the European Battle.Net server.

Comment: Did you download it in English because you had the choice when you bought it (ie, it was available then) or it became available later and you could re-download it without buying it again?

Comment: I bought it in store and French is the only available language in store in France. But once I validated my key in Battle.Net, I was able to download the game in any European language, so I downloaded it in English. I was limited to the European region though.