# If I buy a SC2 digital copy from LA, will I be able to switch to the NA servers?

Tags: starcraft-2

This warning comes on top of the screen when I try to buy the game:

"Retail copies sold in Colombia (your account country) will connect to the Latin America game region."

I so don't want to pay that amount of money to play in a server that seems to be the lowest populated and lowest level server. I don't think its worth it to buy it if I can't choose where to play.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/why-is-starcraft-2-divided-by-regions

Comment: An update: the LA and NA regions are now linked.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Starcraft games are for specific regions only (More specifically, the Activation Key). One copy bought for a specific region cannot be used for a different region.

Comment: Can I then, ask a friend to activate the game in NA and play from here?

Comment: You would need to obtain the NA version of the game (different versions are coded to connect to different servers). If he bought it through the blizzard store for you, you would just log in there and download that version with the login information.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy an online download for NA servers through Blizzard's website. But the game will be in english (which I thought was an advantage - the Brazilian dub is terrible).